# Use an .obj file like a normal BoxGeometry with Three JS

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I would like to use an object file the same way I would use a BoxGeometry in three.js (like adding material and stuff), is there a way to do this?

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: You want your .obj geometry as a class? You would have to write the class. Take a look at the geometry classes [HERE](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/src/geometries).

Comment: There are [several examples](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=obj#webgl_loader_obj) of loading an OBJ file using THREE.OBJLoader. Once you've loaded a model you can add materials to it like any other THREE.Mesh, although your model will UVs if you want to add textures. For more help you'll need to include more information about what you've tried.